# PlayN start up?

Tags: playn

i'm newbie on the PlayN. I read the article over the googlecode: [Getting start](https://code.google.com/p/playn/)

I want to start up with Eciplse but according to the tulorial, I found that we need to install maven, but I'm not getting the way from I start my own Project.

For the help :

[link 1] (playn-2011.appspot.com)

[link 2] (proppy-playn101.appspot.com)

But there is not the way of installation. So, if somebody have an idea what should i do to start. Please help me out to set up the PlayN. thanks In advance

Comment: Why don't you want to use maven?

Comment: I'm getting the problem through this ... I don't have the good tut to start up with this ....!!!

Comment: Just read this article http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/GettingStarted. You will find there some information about how to create new playN project.

Comment: okay .... I"ll try to do from this ...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood if you're not getting how to install `maven` or how to "install" PlayN.

Maven is a kind of portable app. To install it, you just have to download it, unzip it somewhere, and set the path to it's `bin` folder into your `$PATH` variable.

About PlayN, it is not something you "install". PlayN can be seen as a set of Java libraries that let you create multiplatform games. You can create a new PlayN project with `maven` running the following command on a terminal/command prompt:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.googlecode.playn -DarchetypeArtifactId=playn-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.6
```

This command creates a blank project using the latest (as of march 2013) version of PlayN. Maven downloads everything you need, so you should'nt worry about downloading by hand anything else besides maven.

Just after creating a new project, it is already possible to compile and test the project using `maven`, just by entering a terminal, changing the directory into the one you created your project and running the following commands: For Java you run the command `mvn test` (and then a window with the game will open), for HTML5 you run `mvn -Phtml integration-test` (and then you can access your game via browser, using `localhost:8080`), and for Android you run `mvn -Pandroid install` (assuming you have an Android device connected to your computer, or a running emulator instance)

Hope I could be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

When I've created a PlayN project the last time, I found out that eclipse maven integration had an issue for creating new project. The following worked for me:

Creating project using PlayN archetype like gnumaru mentioned:

> mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.googlecode.playn
>   -DarchetypeArtifactId=playn-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.6

After that I've imported the project in Eclipse just like the import of the showcases is done.
I've recently created a small tutorial with screenshots on how to import the showcases, you can find it [here](http://programmerintrouble.blogspot.de/2013/04/getting-started-with-eclipse-and-playn.html)

Hope this was helpful